# How to remap the 'Switch to another tab' shortcut in web browser

Tags: shortcut-keys, google-chrome, browser

I want to remap the keyboard shortcut of "Switch to the next tab" and "Switch to the previous tab", at least in Google Chrome, but I can't find how to do it. The defaults are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and I want to change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily accomplished using [Autokey](https://code.google.com/archive/p/autokey/) in the following manner.

Note: Don't forget to add Autokey to the startup. (You can do this using Startup Applications or Gnome Tweak Tool or whatever tool your flavor has to configure startup items)

You need to set a phrase using whatever your browser currently uses to switch tabs (in most I have used its default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> as you said) and remap that hotkey to whatever you like:

[Re-map example screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIRbb.png)

In my case I use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left or Right</kbd> combination.

You also want to set a Window Filter for this particular one, since the default shortcut for switching tabs in browsers is used for many other things in other applications, and you don't want your keyboard shortcuts to be a pain in the ass later on.

If there is an easier, quicker way to do this, I could not found it, but befriending Autokey is one of the best things that happened in my short experience with linux.